# Which hook to use to insert JavaScript variable from node data

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I have the following function working as a proof of concept to insert a js variable from a node field.

It's in `hook_preprocess_html()` because the js is already rendered in later hooks. Normally I would get the variable from `$vars['node']` but I don't think it exists in `hook_preprocess_html()`?

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $reference = $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'][47]['field_reference']['#items'][0]['value'];
  drupal_add_js(array(
    'field_reference' => $reference
  ), 'setting');
}
```

Is there a better way to access the node field variable, in a later hook perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a node object is not available in the variables passed to the preprocess function, then you can get a node object from [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object), which by default returns an object for the node whose ID is passed as second element of the URL (e.g. "node/1"). If the path doesn't start with "node," which means the page being shown is not a node page, then the function will return `NULL`.

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // The URL for the page being shown is node/<nid>.
}
```

If you want to use a preprocess function for which the node object is passed in the `$variables` array, then you can use `hook_preprocess_page()`, for which `$variables['node']` could also be empty, or `hook_preprocess_node()`, for which the node object is always passed in `$variables['node']`.